# Thank you for helping me (out) VS Thank you for being of help

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

Could you please help me to find out how the sentences below differ in meaning?

> - **Thank you for helping me.**
> - **Thank you for helping me out.** [It strikes me as an informal way of saying just "thank you for helping me, but I'm not sure]
> - **Thank you for being of help.** [to me it sounds awkward, but I see people use this form]

I wonder if you also let me know about my taking on each case.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

- **Thank for helping me** appropriate in almost all circumstances, eg someone in a shop, a teacher
- **... helping me out** very similar but suggests you had a problem which you no longer have
- **... being of help** rather formal, not used so much

Also

- **... being so helpful** for someone doing something more than required, such as getting a lot of advice in a shop